# Error: UserCreatePayload.viewer field type must be Output Type but got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay

The code below works when the entire schema is in a single file, but I'm getting the above error when I try to split it into individual files.

I'm importing all the types and functions.

I have to add more details, but I'm not sure what to say. I think it's a sequencing problem since it works in a single file, but not split up.

Thanks a lot.

```
const UserCreateMutation = mutationWithClientMutationId({
  name: 'UserCreate',
  inputFields: {
    email: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
    password: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)}
  },
  outputFields: {
    viewer: {
      type: viewerType,
      resolve() {
        return viewerGet();
      }
    },
    field: {
      type: userType,
      resolve(node) {
        return node;
      }
    }
  },
  async mutateAndGetPayload({email, password}, {db, req}) {
```

---

```
export const viewerType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Viewer',
  fields() {
    return {
      id: globalIdField('Viewer', ({_id: viewerLocalId}) => {
        return viewerLocalId;
      }),
      _id: {type: GraphQLID},
      user: {
        type: userType,
        resolve(parent, args, {req: {user}}) {
          return user || {};
        }
      },
      profile: {
        type: profileConnectionType,
        args: {
          id: {type: GraphQLID},
          searchTerm: {type: GraphQLString},
          ...connectionArgs
        },
        resolve(parent, {id: profileGlobalId, searchTerm, ...connectionArgs}, {db}) {
          const query = (() => {
            const q = {};

            if (profileGlobalId) {
              const {id: profileLocalId} = fromGlobalId(profileGlobalId);

              Object.assign(
                q,
                {_id: new ObjectID(profileLocalId)}
              );
            }

            if (searchTerm) {
              Object.assign(
                q,
                {
                  $text: {
                    $search: `\"${searchTerm}\"`
                  }
                }
              );
            }

            return q;
          })();
          const sort = {_id: -1};
          const limit = 0;

          return connectionFromPromisedArray(
            promisedArrayGet(
              query,
              sort,
              limit,
              profileCollectionName,
              db
            ),
            connectionArgs
          );
        }
      }
    };
  },
  interfaces: [nodeInterface]
});
```

---

```
class Viewer extends Object {}
export const viewerGet = () => {
  return Object.assign(
    new Viewer(),
    {
      _id: 'Viewer'
    }
  );
};
```

import { viewerType, userType, viewerGet }

Comment: Please Update the Question with the import of viewerType and the viewerType ObjectType

Comment: I added the viewerType and Object

Comment: splitting them into modules and a normal `module.exports` just works fine

Comment: I did it for the viewerType, viewerGet, userType, and UserCreateMutation. Still got the same error. It will take me awhile to redo the whole app. Do you think that's necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem but sometimes module-loading order is an issue. If it is the problem, you can solve it by making `outputFields` a *thunk*, i.e. a function that returns the object instead of a plain object.

```
outputFields: () => ({
  viewer: {
    type: viewerType,
    resolve() {
      return viewerGet();
    }
  },
  field: {
    type: userType,
    resolve(node) {
      return node;
    }
  }
}),
```

Comment: I still got the same error. I'll go through everything and see where I can add other thunks too.